# Swift change only UIImageView's size

Tags: swift

I have got this Swift code

```
let background_image: UIImageView = {
    let im = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backg")
    let view=UIImageView()
    view.image=im
    return view
}()
```

And it's size is set to 300x300.I only want `background_image` size to be 300x300,but `im`'s size to stay as it was originally.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Thanks for the link! Apples documentation is the most nebulous thing ever!

Comment: contentMode is an attribute of UIView, so it's a bit hidden.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ which content mode shalt i use?

Comment: Depends on what you want https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontentmode

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ let me explain this to you int HTML.I have a div and image in div,div's size is 300x300px and image's size is 200x800.I want to set my css so it won't shrink image to 300x300 rather it will make it's width 300 but will show only 300px of image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136790/discussion-between-peejweej-and-siajsaj-ijsaijsaja).